# Segmentation Fault during Debugging C++

Tags: c++, class, vector, segmentation-fault, stack

So, have an assignment where I need to solve the N-Queens* problem using the stack.

*N-Queens problem: you have a chessboard with N rows/columns/queens. You must place each queen so that it cannot attack any of the others on the board.

I created a Queen class just to store the row and column positions for each valid queen placed, and that is working fine. As far as I can tell, all of my sorting and checking logic is also fine. However, either in main or my solve function, I'm getting a Segmentation Fault, but only when I debug. When ran normally, it just exits. My debugger unfortunately doesn't let me go line by line, but I've manually done so and still can't figure this out.

```
void solve(int k, int N)
{
stack<Queen> queenStack;
if(k == N)
    {
    while(!queenStack.empty())
        {
        cout << queenStack.top().rowPos << ", " << queenStack.top().colPos << endl;
        queenStack.pop();
        }//end while 
    }//endif

else
    {
    for (int i = 0;i < N; i++)
        {
        if (isSafe(k,i))
            {
            Queen queen(k,i);
            queenStack.push(queen);
            solve(k++,N);
            }//end if
        else
            {
            if(queenStack.empty())
                {
                break;
                }//end if
            else
                {
                queenStack.pop();
                k--;
                }//end else
            }//end else
         }//end for
    }//end else
}//end void
```

then my main:

```
int main()
{
int N = 0;
cout << "Please pick an integer 3 or greater and less than whatever you think won't crash your computer." << endl;
cin >> N;
while (N < 3)
    {
    cout << "Please pick an integer 3 or greater and less than whatever you think won't crash your computer." <<
    endl;
    cin >> N;
    }//end while
solve(0,N);
return 0;
}//end main
```

my ifSafe is a bool function that just does checks based on row, which I pass in as an int, and then return the true/false for the loop.

Comment: `queenStack` is local to the `solve` function. Adding to it before your recursion does not affect that call.

Comment: so I need to create the stack in main, pass it into the function, and then use the function to add to it? if I'm understanding properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, there's an obvious issue in your code that will immediately lead to a stack overrun. The way you recursively call your solve function:

```
solve(k++,N);
```

Will first call `solve`, and then increment `k`. So `solve(0, N)` calls to `solve(0, N)`, which in turn calls to `solve(0, N)` leading to stack overrun. There's no side effects or any external variables that would affect `solve` and make it behave differently with the same arguments.

I don't fully understand your solution, so I can't tell you how to fix it, but most likely your intent was for `queenStack` to be visible across the calls, in which case it would make sense to make it global, or to pass it into the `solve` by reference.

Now to why it finishes just fine when you run it outside of the debugger. My guess would be that you use some kind of non-windows system (mac or linux) and run it from the terminal. This way the program still crashes, but does not show it in any obvious way. The way to see if it finished successfully is to print `$?` after executing a program:

```
a@a-dev:~$ ./crash_me
a@a-dev:~$ echo $?
1
```

If the program executed normally, the return code should be zero.